# WPF binding to DataContext with class and subclass

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am playing with databinding in wpf and I encountered a problem. Here is my code:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpf"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">    
    <StackPanel Name="stackpanel">
        <TextBox Name="tb1" Text="{Binding Path=A.Number}" />
        <TextBox Name="tb2" Text="{Binding Path=B.Number}" />
        <TextBlock Name="tbResult" Text="{Binding Path=C}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.A = new MySubClass();
        myClass.B = new MySubClass();
        stackpanel.DataContext = myClass;
    }
}
```

**MyClass.cs**

```
class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MySubClass a;
    public MySubClass A 
    {
        get { return a; }
        set
        {
            a = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("A");
            OnPropertyChanged("C");
        }
    }

    private MySubClass b;
    public MySubClass B 
    {
        get { return b; }
        set
        {
            b = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("B");
            OnPropertyChanged("C");
        }
    }

    public int C
    {
        get { return A.Number + B.Number; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }        
}
```

**MySubClass.cs**

```
class MySubClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int number;
    public int Number 
    {
        get { return number; }
        set
        {
            number = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Number");
        }
    }

    public MySubClass()
    {
        Number = 1;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }     
}
```

Now, the problem is that binding works fine, after I run the app. Also, values A.Number and B.Number are updating fine as I change them in textbox. But variable C in MyClass.C is updated only when app starts and never after. What do I need to change so that C updates when I change A.Number or B.Number. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When updating your data model, do you change the Number directly on the MySubClass instances or do you assign new subclasses to the MyClass instance? i.e:

```
myClass.A.Number = 5; // will trigger OnPropertyChanged on MySubClass, but not on MyClass
```

will not trigger OnPropertyChanged on the A (but will of course update A.Number). 
For this to work you have to do something like:

```
MySubClass v = new MySubClass()
v.Number = 5;
myClass.A = v;  // will trigger OnPropertyChanged on MyClass
```

---

Updated answer. YOu could do this to catch any property changes in a and b.

```
public MyClass()
{
    a.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(UpdateC);
    b.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(UpdateC);
}

void UpdateC(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged("C");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but is it possible somehow to update property C without instantiating MySubClass

Answer (score 1):

> What do I need to change so that C updates when I change A.Number or B.Number.

You need to listen for changes to A and B properties. It should work if you add this code to A setter:

```
set
{
if (a != null)
{
 a.PropertyChanged-=NumberChanged;
}
 a = value;
 a.PropertyChanged+=NumberChanged;
 OnPropertyChanged("A");
 OnPropertyChanged("C");
}

private void NumberChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.PropertyName == "Number")
  {
    OnPropertyChanged("C");
  }
}
```

and the same for B setter.